# Galois actions and smooth-proper base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $k$ of finite type over a finite field.

The Galois group $\text{Gal}(k^{\rm sep}/k)$ acts on $H^j_{\rm ét}(X_{k^{\rm sep}},\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(n))$ continuously, where $H^j$ has the $\ell$-adic topology.

We may spread out $X_k$ to a smooth proper model $\mathcal{X}\to S$ with $S$ connected of finite type over a finite field.

Let $s\in S$ be a closed point.

By the smooth and proper base-change theorem, we have an isomorphism of continuous Galois-modules

$$H^j(X_{k^{\rm sep}},\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(n))\simeq H^j(X_{\overline{s}},\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(n))$$

and the action of $\text{Gal}(k^{\rm sep}/k)$ is sent to the action of $\text{Gal}(\kappa(s)^{\rm sep}/\kappa(s))$ on the right side, hence factors through it on the left side.

We have:

$$H^i_{\rm cont}(\text{Gal}(k^{\rm sep}/k), H^j(X_{k^{\rm sep}},\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(n))) = H^i_{\rm cont}(\text{Gal}(\kappa(s)^{\rm sep}/\kappa(s)), H^j(X_{\overline{s}},\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(n))) $$

This looks dubious. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a quotient of $G$.  Let $M$ be a $G$-module such that the action of $G$ on $M$ factors through $H$.  Then there is a map $H^i(H, M)\to H^i(G, M)$, but it is not in general an isomorphism; the difference in general is controlled by the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence.  Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: There is a more basic problem: since $k$ isn't the fraction field of the henselian local ring at $s$, there isn't even a map from the Galois group of $k$ to that of $\kappa(s)$, so it doesn't make any sense to say that the action of the former "is sent to" the action of the latter. The Galois group of $k$ is "too big".  It is only (for normal $S$) the *subgroup* of the former given by the Galois group of the fraction field of the henselian local ring at $s$ (a "decomposition group" at $s$ when $S$ is Dedekind, for example) whose action "is sent to" the acton of the Galois group of $\kappa(s)$.